# Recording unsaved Excel data with python or automsaving with vba

Tags: python, excel, recording

Using python, I want to continuously record some Excel calculations.  The python/excel functions I have used will only read excel data from a saved spreadsheet.  Is there a way to read unsaved data?

If not, is there a way to save excel and read the saved data periodically?  I tried saving my sheets periodically (with a macro) but this is problematic if I am interacting with the spreadsheet during a save.  Instead of saving my spreadsheet, excel saves a copy with a random name.  If there is a way to remedy this (maybe some kind of vba error handling) that may solve the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Excel on Windows and not OS X, you can try the win32com.client module, which you can get by installing the Python for Windows package:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Unfortunately, the available documentation is pretty spotty at best... here's a start:

http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html

I should warn you that the COM API isn't very easy to use, so you are really better off sticking with VBA if your workflow requires Excel.

VBA error handling: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm